# Verify all fields are entered correctly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium and python to fill out a form. I need to verify if each field is entered correctly. There are 3 different fields:

1. field is a radio button **(I need to verify if the circle next to a name is selected)**
2. field is a drop down menu selection **(I need to verify that a name is selected)**
3. is a text field **(I need to verify that the entered text is correct)**

I know that I can use `assert "name" in driver.page_source` in order to test if the word is on the page, but that is not what I am trying to do. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [is_selected()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) will help you with the radio and select items:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('item_id').is_selected()
```

For the text field, use [get_attribute](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute):

```
driver.find_element_by_id('item_id').get_attribute("value")
```